Capillary action question
I have noticed something odd.  I use a straw to drink.  When I drink Sprite, the straw often drips Sprite on my desk.  No other beverages drip.  It doesn't seem to be related to carbonation, since Fanta doesn't drip.  It doesn't seem related to temperature, as the Sprite will drip whether it's right out of the fridge or if it's room temperature.  It doesn't seem related to any bends in the straw; it will drip whether the straw is straight or bent.  It doesn't seem to depend on how recently I have taken a sip; it might drip soon after I set it down or it might drip 5 minutes later.
I think it's a capillary action issue, but I'm confused as to what exactly is happening.

Can you please add a picture of the sprite setup. I wonder if its related to carbonation levels and overall composition of the sprite drink, resulting in a lower surface tension and the straw liquid getting pushed by escaping carbon dioxide, thereby causing this drip. How many drinks have you tried so far. Can you try a few things: 1) Let the sprite go flat by stirring it and then check. 2) Check with regular soda water (fully carbonated). This will help us understand it better. Also, what is your altitude?

In small tubes, the tendency for "slugs" of liquid to get stuck in the tube between air-filled spaces depends sensitively on the contact angle between the liquid and the inside walls of the tube, and the surface tension of the liquid. Slug trapping means that the liquid will not run out the end of the tube by gravity unless you shake it or whip it around violently.
This effect is responsible for the water in a rabbit-watering tube staying put in the tube unless the rabbit licks the end of the tube where the meniscus resides.
Liquid that runs readily out of a tipped tube has low surface tension and high contact angle (the liquid meniscus is easily stretched and the liquid adheres poorly to the tube wall). High surface tension and low contact angle means it takes work to deform the meniscus and it likes to stick to the tube wall- and tends not to run out of the tube.
To get farther than this in the analysis requires knowledge of the surface tension of your liquid and the wetting angle of the liquid on the tube wall.
Note that these effects are strongly modulated by the diameter of the tube. Large tubes allow liquid to run out while air runs in simultaneously (this is called two-phase flow). Small tubes favor trapping.
